# How to rename the column in particular String array in Java

Tags: java

How to rename the column in particular String array in Java

```
String strList [] = new String[]{"a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "b", "B", "A", "","a" };
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String str: strList){
        if(str == null || str.isEmpty()){
            str = "Header";
        }

        if(isValueContains(str, resultList)){
            String [] elements = str.split("_");
            String lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
            int elementInt = getInteger(lastElement);
            elementInt++;

            resultList.add(str+"_"+elementInt);
        }else{
            resultList.add(str);
        }

    }
```

The column should be displayed as a, b, a1, c, b1, b2, b3, a2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
    String strList[] = new String[]{"a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "b", "B", "A", "", "a"};
    Map<String, Integer> strAppearancesCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Integer strCount;

    for (String str : strList)
    {
        if (str == null || str.isEmpty())
        {
            str = "Header";
        }

        str = str.toLowerCase();

        if (strAppearancesCount.containsKey(str))
        {
            strCount = strAppearancesCount.get(str) + 1;
            resultList.add(str + strCount);
        }
        else
        {
            resultList.add(str);
            strCount = 0;
        }

        strAppearancesCount.put(str, strCount);
    }

    System.out.println(resultList);
```